# Android camera application that allows earbud mic clicker to snap pictures?

Tags: android, smartphone, android-app

Is there an Android application that allows a user to snap pictures by clicking the microphone or volume button(s) located on earbuds? I'd rather use this than touching anything on the smartphone.

Comment: This MAY be more on topic over at [android.se], as it is about the function of the operating system rather than a photography specific piece of technology. For instance I could ask "Is there an app that allows me to make the phone do a dance with the buttons located on the earphones." :)

Comment: Does it have to be that specific button or just anything that will trigger the camera without touching the phone?

Comment: @inkista Anything that will trigger the camera without toughing the phone. So even some bluetooth gadget would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

[TriggerTrap Mobile](http://triggertrap.com/products/apps/mobile/) is a smartphone app that lets you trigger the shutter of the phone's camera by sound (i.e., clapping or snapping your fingers will do it). While it's mostly designed to be a "smart" cable release for a camera with a cable release port, it also works with the built-in camera on the phone.